# CPT archive redirects to single post

Tags: posts, customization

Ok, the title does not help too much, so let me try and explain.

It's a Genesis-based website.

I created a CPT:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_livestreams() {

/**
 * Post Type: live streams.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Live stream', '' ),
    "menu_name" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
    "all_items" => __( 'All live streams', '' ),
    "add_new" => __( 'Add new live stream', '' ),
    "add_new_item" => __( 'Add new live stream', '' ),
    "edit_item" => __( 'Edit live stream', '' ),
    "view_item" => __( 'New live stream', '' ),
    "view_items" => __( 'View live streams', '' ),
    "search_items" => __( 'Search live streams', '' ),
    "archives" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "live-stream", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "thumbnail", "genesis-cpt-archives-settings", 'genesis-seo' ),
    'yarpp_support' => true,
);

register_post_type( "livestreams", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_livestreams' );
```

I also created a file: **archive-livestreams.php**

For some unknown reason when I go to https://inthebunch.co.za/live-stream/ it redirects me to the latest post created within that post type.

I cleared cache, re-saved permalinks etc... any advice?

Comment: What does archive-livestreams.php look like?

Comment: Is it a redirect to a specific post url? If yes, what is the url?

Comment: @JacobPeattie  here is the code I currently have in there.

`<?php
    
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
    
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
    add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
    
        
genesis();`

Comment: @Robbert not a specific url, seems to always go to the latest post created in the cpt, in this case it is: https://inthebunch.co.za/live-stream/live-stream-uae-tour/, previously it redirected to https://inthebunch.co.za/live-stream/live-stream-volta-ao-algarve/

Comment: What if you empty your archive-livestreams.php?

Comment: @Robbert no change I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of your archive is `https://inthebunch.co.za/livestreams/`.

Have a look at [the docs for `register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), specifically, the description for the `has_archive` argument:

> **has_archive**
>   (boolean or string) (optional) Enables post type archives. *Will use $post_type as archive slug by default*.
>   Default: false

In the case of your code, `$post_type` is `livestreams`:

```
register_post_type( "livestreams", $args );
```

If you want to change that value, you can supply a string for `has_archive`:

```
"has_archive" => "live-stream",
```